# Android-APP Rating with RatingBar

Tags: android, google-play, rating

I just want to integrate an visual in-app prompt-dialog ("Rate this App"). I found a lot of libraries with a simple button which is linked to the google play store site.

Is there any library with a prompt-dialog that integrates the stars (RatingBar)? With this option the users don't have to visit the google-play-store-site...

If someone has a function to set rating to google-play, than i would develop my own prompt-dialog.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, it isnt allowed by google.

Comment: Are you sure? What about that: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1032. Maybe someone has try it?!

Comment: If you read the description "With a little twist: if the rating is positive, we take the user to the Play Store directly. Otherwise, we ask him for feedback via email. (This is all configurable.)"
What that library does is just ask the user to rate two times the app.